# Answering questions that weren't asked

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I was half way through writing a question for ServerFault. As I went to take a screenshot of the problem, I tried something different and stumbled on the answer.

I didn't get to ask the question, which means there's nothing to answer anymore. There still won't be a search result in ServerFault the next time I or someone else has the same problem in 3 months time.

I thought that perhaps I could still post my original question ("How do I..."), but in the body, include the answer I found. What's the StackOverflow community consensus on this? Is it appropriate or does it break a StackOverflow law?

Comment: What is the example? Why didn't you post this on [Meta Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/)? ... and if you do answer your own question, you should include it as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing questions just because the OP knows the answer: good or bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39236/closing-questions-just-because-the-op-knows-the-answer-good-or-bad)