# Should I post questions when they're answered even before I post them?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Ok, this title may not make sense, but please bear with me :)

I recently found myself puzzled by something in FluentNHibernate: a weird mapping artifact was popping to say hello to classes it had no relatioship to. After scratching my head, banging it a bit against the desk, I proceeded to search for info.

After a while, I decided to ask the SO community:

> I'm seeing seomthing really weird in a
>   project using Asp.Net MVC on the
>   NHibernate stack (that is
>   FluentNhibernate, NHibernate,
>   NHibernate.Search and Lucene.net)
>
> I have two POCO classes (called here
>   `ReferencesThingie` and
>   `AlsoReferencesThingie`) that both
>   reference a third object (called
>   `Thingie`, my naming convention **is**
>   cold and efficient) and ...

And then the following happens, while I'm typing the question

- "Hey, I forgot to check the current versions, maybe that'll help..."
- "Mhhh, weird, i didn't notice that"
- "Wait a second, I have to add this info to the SO question"
- "Wow! I smell a rat!!!"
- "Victory! Problem solved!"

So here's where I'm at. I'm looking at a question I didn't ask, already formatted and mostly documented with solid facts. Seems like a waste to not ask it, but I already have the solution. What should I do with it?

- Ask it and answer it right away after?
- Keep it to myself; if I managed, others will?

What's the official take on these non-questions (let's call them facts)? Wouldn't that lead to people adding facts to the site, not coming back even in the case of a better answer, thinking that question and answer are a little capsule that shall not be broken? Because let's face it, even if somebody pointed out a better way, the way I've worked and sweated for may always seem sweeter...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault)

Comment: `Should i post questions when they're answered even before i post them?` You ran into Jon, did you? ;)

Comment: I didn't ran into Jon. I must ask too few questions (or too obscure ones) for him to pay attention ;)

Comment: @ChrisF, i'm not sure it's the same since the question is answered live while being typed. Bogdan_Ch seems to approach the problem by first having a good idea, then formulating it as a question, then answering it directly. Here i'm wondering about the question and it's live answer being worth posted, with all their cruft and before being refined to a blog post

Comment: @samy - there have been other meta questions about answering your own question and a lot of them have been closed as a duplicates of that one. Maybe it was the wrong master question.

Comment: @ChrisF - i'd argue that i'm not wondering about answering my own question, and rather about posting it in the first place :) but i see how my question relates to the one you're linking to. I have the feeling that posting a blog post (ie a question you already know the answer to, answer that you may have prepared in advance and proofread) and posting a question you've answered while typing it is different but it doesn't change the end result so...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39236/closing-questions-just-because-the-op-knows-the-answer-good-or-bad

Comment: Exact dupe of an entry in the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I say ask away!

Personally, I would ask the question and wait for a bit before you provide your own answer - you never know, the community may come up with a better answer than the one you already have!

If no one comes up with an acceptable answer in a day or so, go ahead and answer your own question.

This is why chat conversations with my brother (who is a better coder than I) often go like this:

> Me: question for you
>   Him: okay, shoot
>   Me: I'm keep getting a NullReference error from my class
>   (five minutes pass by, his chat window says "Jared is typing a message")
>   Him: well? do you have a question or not?
>   Me: yeah, never mind, I'm dumb

Almost every time I try to explain the problem I'm having, I end up finding the bug in my code (or that one place I forgot to pass a value, etc). Let's just say I end up typing "yeah, I'm dumb" quite a bit.

Comment: Yay for rubberducking!

Comment: @Piskvor - cool, now I learned something! Thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Same thing here, but i must confess i never had the idea to ask an inanimated object; i prefer coworkers, and the "duh" moment i have when the bug jumps at me in front of them :)

Comment: Depends on the coworkers... :-P    Sometimes you'd be better off with the inanimate object!

Answer (score 0):

Self Answering is acceptable on SO.  You can do so right away, though you have to wait two days before you can accept it.  We want the site to be a complete repository of Q & A.